# How does inheritance work with for-each loops?

Tags: java, inheritance, foreach

How does inheritance work in relation to a for-each loop?  Imagine I have two classes: `SubClass` and `SuperClass`, and I have the following `ArrayList`.

```
/**
* Containes both SuperClass and SubClass instances.
*/
ArrayList<SuperClass> superClasses = new ArrayList<SuperClass>();
```

Is it possible to iterate over `superClasses` in such a way as to only select `subClasses`.

The following:

```
for(SubClass subClass : superClasses){
    // Do Foo
}
```

does not do this.
The following is the only thing that I could get to work:

```
for(SuperClass superClass : superClasses){
    if(superClass instanceof SubClass){
        // Do Foo
    }
}
```

However I do not want to use `instanceof` unless absolutely necessary, as I keep reading everywhere (StackOverflow, Oracle Tutorials etc) that one can almost always find a better solution that increases encapsulation.  Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: No , not one I can think of . You need to use `instanceof` !

Comment: Somewhat similar question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623255/java-for-each-loop-iteration-over-extended-objects

Comment: @maxf130 The advice you keep reading isn't suggesting `instanceof` is an evil keyword. Instead, I suspect it is saying that regular use of `instanceof` indicates a sub-optimal design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could write a helper method to hide the `instanceof` test... [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a method like this, for example, in [`Iterables.filter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class%29), which you could use like this:

```
for (SubClass subclass : Iterables.filter(superclasses, SubClass.class)) {
    ...
}
```

It's only moving the `instanceof` check though really - it's not getting rid of it. Fundamentally you *need* that check, because something's got to do the filtering.

Answer (score 2):

The first approach (`for (SubClass subClass : superClasses)`) cannot work as the compiler cannot ensure that there are only objects of tyoe `SubClass` in there.

In Java (without external libraries) it is not possible to preselect on the `Class`. Therefore the `instanceof` is the normal way to do this.

Comment: I stated that it contains both Sub- and SuperClass instances.

Comment: @maxf130 I chaned my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` would work absolutely fine in this situation. But if you really do have reasons for not using it you could always give the superclass some variable, `Boolean skipMe = true`, and change that to false in the subclass if you wanted.

But I suggest using `instanceof`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to manage a separate List which only contains instances of SubClass, if possible.

Comment: _if possible_  It isn't :)